# Spring boot two data sources, unit tests stopped working

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have switched my application to use two data sources, the code runs fine and both are picked up, however my unit tests have started to fail, code is below, help much appreciated.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:180)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 71 more
```

application.properties (in main and in test folders):

```
datasource.primary.url = <url>
datasource.primary.username = <user>
datasource.primary.password = <password>

datasource.secondary.url = <url>
datasource.secondary.username = <user>
datasource.secondary.password = <pass>
```

Main program:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EntityScan({"com.example.domain","com.example.common.domain"})
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
@EnableScheduling
    public class MyApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
}

  }
```

Primary Data source config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.repository", 
entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManagerFactory", 
transactionManagerRef = "primaryTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PrimaryConfiguration {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.primary")
@Primary
public DataSource primaryDataSource()
{
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder)
{
    return builder
            .dataSource(primaryDataSource())
            .packages("uk.gov.dwp.pss.roc.domain")
            .persistenceUnit("primaryPersistenceUnit")
            .build();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public JpaTransactionManager primaryTransactionManager(@Qualifier("primaryEntityManagerFactory") final EntityManagerFactory factory)
{
    return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
}
}
```

Secondary config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.common.repository", 
entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory", 
transactionManagerRef = "secondaryTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SecondaryConfiguration {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.secondary")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource()
{
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondaryEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder)
{
    return builder
            .dataSource(secondaryDataSource())
            .packages("uk.gov.dwp.pss.commons.domain.security")
            .persistenceUnit("secondaryPersistenceUnit")
            .build();
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager secondaryTransactionManager(@Qualifier("secondaryEntityManagerFactory") final EntityManagerFactory factory)
{
    return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
}

}
```

Repository class:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyObject, String>,JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyObject> {
}
```

Unit test class use annotation:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

A database driver was not found on the classpath for the AutoConfiguration to setup while running your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

As @ndrone stated you need to set your database driver. It is unclear if you are attempting to use AutoConfigureTestDatabase. If so you should reference [AutoConfigureTestDatabase](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/jdbc/AutoConfigureTestDatabase.html) from the Spring Boot docs.

If this is the case you could specify the Embedded database to use by using the following in your test (configuration):

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
```

Otherwise, you could modify your application.properties in your test folder to specify the connection type such as:

```
datasource.primary.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
datasource.secondary.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

Comment: I have added the database driver to my application properties file, and still get the exact same error.  I am not attempting to use AutoConfigureTestDatabase